# Click link in email using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In my application I have to verify the email notification in Gmailm and the email has a link to register the user. I am able to read the email using JavaMail API, but I'm not able to extract the hyperlink available in it.

The email content is mimetype, and I am able to read it using multipart, but I'm not able to extract the HTML content from it.

```java
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX"); 
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY); 
Message messages[] = emailFolder.getMessages(); 
for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) { 
   Message message = messages[i];   
   if(message.getSubject().contains("Email Verification")){  
      Object object = message.getContent(); 
      Multipart multipart = (Multipart) object; 
      BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(0); 
      object = bodyPart.getContent(); 
      multipart.getBodyPart(1); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Um, what have you tried?  Can you read the content of the message as a String.  Does the String contain the html content?  Can you search the html content for the link?

Comment: The email content is mimetype and I am able to read it using multipart. But I am not able to extract the html content from it.

Comment: Why not?  What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
       emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
       Message messages[] = emailFolder.getMessages();
       for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
          Message message = messages[i];         
           if(message.getSubject().contains("Email Verification")){
            Object object = message.getContent();
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) object;
            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(0);
              object = bodyPart.getContent();
              multipart.getBodyPart(1);            }
       }

Comment: Have mentioned the code. Can you tell me how do i extract only the html content from it

Comment: Does [this example code in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) help?